# Unable to echo $_POST data? Why won't this code work?

Tags: php

I am running the following test below and entering some text into the first text box out of the 20. I am simply trying to echo out the post value in the `spec.php` page for further processing. When I try it echo's nothing. My question is, how come if I generate input element code using a loop, where every input 'name' attribute is unique, the $_POST variable you would expect to be passed on to `spec.php` does not echo out?

```
<form action="spec.php" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
        echo '<input type="text" style="border:2px solid red;" name="inp'.$i.'" />';
    }

?>
<input type="submit">
```

spec.php

```
echo $_POST['inp0'];
```

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you're getting back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First debug your $_POST with the following:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

See if all your inputs are in there.

Edit:
I just used the following and it works!

```
 <form method="post" action="action.php">
 <?php
  for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
    echo '<input type="text" style="border:2px solid red;" name="inp'.$i.'" />';
  }
  ?>
 <input type="submit">
```

action.php

```
<?php print_r($_POST);
```

result:

```
Array
(
[inp0] => one 
[inp1] => two
[inp2] => three
[inp3] => four 
[inp4] => five
[inp5] => six
[inp6] => seven
[inp7] => blah
[inp8] => blah
[inp9] => blah
[inp10] => blah
[inp11] => blah
[inp12] => 
[inp13] => 
[inp14] => 
[inp15] => 
[inp16] => 
[inp17] => 
[inp18] => 
[inp19] => 
)
```

Comment: Var_dump output is: array(4) { ["inp0"]=> string(0) "" } after I enter some text in the input field for inp0, it seems like the input fields don't get passed on to the 'action script' but the action script is 'aware' that the variable exists.

Comment: There's no reason for that to happen. Standby I'm telling you whats wrong.

Comment: Nope, I just have put it to another page and there's really no reason for it to not work.

Comment: just copy paste the above code to the two separate files. DO NOT miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first field is `$_POST['inp0']`. Look at your loop. It starts at zero.

Comment: Read the question: '... text into the first text box' therefore, it should echo the $_POST value.

Comment: if stuff won't work, my advice is to look at your HTML code after the server work (view source in browser)

Comment: Changing to echo $_POST['inp0'] did not fix the problem. Thanks anyways.